# How the run maven project depending on the shell script in Jenkins server?

Tags: jenkins

i have maven project in github and i run it in jenkins. But I want create simple improvement.

I need determine what to do from project depending on environment variable jenkins. I check `Execute shell` and get this variable, for display I use `echo $BUILD_NUMBER`. How me run project from `Goals and options: compile`, if `echo $(($BUILD_NUMBER%2))` print *0* and form `Goals and options: compile test` if `echo $(($BUILD_NUMBER%2))` print *1*.

*Thanks for the help*

Comment: Describe your views in comments, but do not press down raiting question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use this shell script, and need remove all goal options. For run use ant or maven builder.

```
if [ $(($BUILD_NUMBER % 2)) -eq 0 ]
  then
     echo "run project"
  else
    echo "run tests"
fi
```